# How to create animation for Alert dialogs?

Tags: android, android-animation, customdialog

I have an android application which uses a custom Alert Dialog for showing an image and its description.

I want to make this  dialog

1. Pop up from center like in iPhone.
2. Push down to center  when cancelling.

I know that it is possible by applying animations/styles.How can i make style for this purpose?How to use this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using it in the same activity or you're creating a seperate activity for the dialog box?

Comment: then declare an animation effect in xml in res and call it in your dialog's animation

Comment: see [this page in official site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Dialog, was defined in doc, is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed. With it's subclasses (AlertDialog, ProgressDialog, AppCompatDialog,...), they become a alert system in Android. For making more exciting when they appear/exit, we can set animation for them easily. In this tip, I provide a way to do this trick through styles resource.

http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/10/showing-dialog-with-animation-in-android.html